# Excel formula in java code

Tags: java

Using excel sheet formula in java code, when given a date, month, and year as an input, it should generate the unique id.
When I use that generated unique id as an input, it should in reverse display the proper date, month, and year which was given as an input

```
Input=Date+Month+Year   
Output=generate unique id 

Input=Generated Unique id
Output=Date+Month+Year
```

Comment: What is a "unique id"? Is `20160526` a good "unique id" for May 26, 2016? Or are you looking for the number `42516`, which is the Excel value for May 26, 2016?

Comment: You really need to try yourself and also be more specific with your requirements. Remember, stackoverflow is not a write the code for you service!

Comment: Andreas-id should generate dynamically

Comment: @Meenu What does "generate dynamically" mean? Is the ID *derived* from the date, like I showed? Or is it like a database ID column that is automatically assigned the next sequential number when the next row is inserted, so the ID is not *derived* from the date, but simply *associated* with the date the first time that date is seen? If derived, then which derive algorithm do you want? I showed two options, but there are many more.

Answer (score 2):

You have `java.util.UUID`. You can set either the most or least significant bits of your UUID sequence. Choose to fix the most significant bits to the corresponding date to conform to the standard. Read documentation.